# How to run a function before rendering the Template?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I have a chat room socket program and I am trying to make a web view for that by FLASK. The server is running at the background and the client would connect to that server when the user submitted his name by a HTML form.

So, I have this code in my app.py file. I can see that the client successfully connected in the Python terminal but the template won't render any more.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template , request
import client
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/indexchat.html',methods=['POST'])
def chatroom():
   a = request.form.get('name')
   b=[]
   if a:

      b.append(a)
   client.startclient(a)
 return render_template("indexchat.html",args=b)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

If I remove the client.startclient(a) function the page will render.

Comment: What is the `client.startclient` function/method ? Is that a blocking code ? If so the `render_template` method is never called.

Comment: it is the code should connect to my chat server. so what should i do??

Comment: Can you share it please, I'm guessing it's a blocking connection but I want to make sure.

Comment: sure https://gist.github.com/amir-aa/42c401b2e1f930812d71bf64c9a65b55#file-client-py

Comment: Ok since you use a infinite loop(`while True` at l.43) as long as you don't have any exception the `client.startclient(a)` will block the execution of the code. Remember python is (by default at least) a mono-process/mono-threaded interpreter. So you need to redisign your app to run both the web server(flask) and the chat server independently and use a messaging mechanism to allow them to talk. But that is beyond the scope of your question here. Maybe a solution will be to use [flask-socketio](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thank You so much.it was a great Helpful solution for me Really. but any idea about do this without json ??